# Printing an Array as an Unordered List

Tags: arrays, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm using Bill Erickson [Custom Meta Boxes and Fields for WordPress](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) and was wondering how I'd go about printing an array of checkboxes as an unordered list.

This is what I've got in my theme's functions.php file:

```
array(
'name' => 'Other Features',
'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
'id' => $prefix . 'other_features',
'type' => 'multicheck',
'options' => array(
    'language' => 'English Speaking',
    'furniture' => 'Modern &amp; Classic Furniture',
    'fridge' => 'Fridge/Freezer',
    'stove' => 'Wood Burning Stove',
    'oven' => 'Electric Oven',
    'internet' => 'Free Wi-Fi',
    'tv' => 'Television/DVD Player',
    'plugs' => 'UK Power Plugs',
)
),
```

And this is how it appears in my Add/Edit page panel:
[image]

What I'd like to know how to do is print only the selected checkboxes as an unordered list with their ID, like so:

```
<ul>
    <li id="language">English Speaking</li>
    <li id="furniture">Modern &amp; Classic Furniture</li>
    <li id="stove">Wood Burning Stove</li>
    <li id="oven">Electric Oven</li>
    <li id="internet">Free Wi-Fi</li>
    <li id="tv">Television/DVD Player</li>
</ul>
```

Any help at all to point me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using, courtesy of Bill Erickson himself:

```
<?php
global $post;
$other_features = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'other_features' );
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $other_features as $id => $value )
    echo '<li id="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
?>
```